# RxJava1 vs Rxjava2: Exception in onNext

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

When doing the following in RxJava1, the exception in onNext would be re-routed into the same Subscriber's onError:

```
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList("1", "22", "333", "4444")).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("RxJava1", "onError: " + e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            if (s.length() == 4) {
                Integer test = null;
                test.hashCode();
            }
            Log.d("RxJava1", s + " - " + s.length());
        }
    });
```

output:

```
D/RxJava1: 1 - 1
D/RxJava1: 22 - 2
D/RxJava1: 333 - 3
D/RxJava1: onError: null
```

When doing, as far as I know, the same in RxJava2, this behaviour has changed and no longer returns to onError, but simply crashes:

```
    Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("1", "22", "333", "4444")).subscribeWith(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            if (s.length() == 4) {
                Integer test = null;
                test.hashCode();
            }
            Log.d("RxJava2", s + " - " + s.length());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("RxJava2", "onError: " + e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

Output:

```
D/RxJava2: 1 - 1
D/RxJava2: 22 - 2
D/RxJava2: 333 - 3
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

I'd mostly like to know, which of the 2 versions is doing it "wrong"?
Was this a bug in RxJava1 that has been fixed? Is this a bug in RxJava2? 
Or has this not been a conscious change in the first place, since I can't find any details about this?

ps. I did notice that wrapping this into 'SafeObserver' re-routes to onError again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is wrong, the two versions have different design constraints. In 2.x the `Observer`/`Subscriber` can't throw from its `onXXX` methods.

If you use the 1-2-3 argument `subscribe()` methods in 2.x you are covered. Otherwise if you really can't fix your `onNext` use `safeSubscribe()`.